# How to change my svn branch?

Tags: svn

I created a branch to a part of a big svn repository, a while ago, having my name (enterprise policy):

```
-svn/branch/myname
   |-file1
   |-file2
   |-folderA
   |-folderB
```

Now I have to work on another part and I would like to create a folder inside my branch, but like this I will have a branch with my name that contains the files and the folders in the folder I created my branch on and the other folder, that is a branch linked to another folder in the big repository:

```
-svn/branch/myname
   |-file1
   |-file2
   |-folderA
   |-folderB
   |-branch2someOtherThing
```

I am wondering is there a way to move all the branch inside a folder first? I would like to have something like:

```
-svn/branch/myname
   |-branch2FirstThing
      |-file1
      |-file2
      |-folderA
      |-folderB
   |-branch2someOtherThing
      |-content of OtherThing
```

If there is such a possibility, which is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, do not try to get a mixed working copy where some directories are from 1 repo, and others from another... you'll get in a mess.

Now, you can use externals to map a path in a different branch or repo to a directory in your repo. This will checkout the foreign path as if it were part of your own repo. This may be what you want.

Generally, just create a new working copy  and checkout your 2nd branch there. Really easy.